# How to Design a Scheduler that Works on Documents updated between a fixed time Interval?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, backend, scheduler

I am designing a scheduler that sends docs updated in last hour to some other system every hour i.e docs updated between last job and current job.

I have updated at fields in my docs, which allows me to query my db to get docs whose updated field lies between my current time and last job time. This means I have to Index my updated at field. I am not sure if it's a good practice to index my time field in db. Is this a good practice or is there a better way to do this?